# How can I export a voice memo from my app to iPhone's voice memo app?

Tags: ios, export, voice, memo

Is it possible to  export a .wav file to Voice memo app from my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the current versions of iOS, it's impossible. We cannot access the Voice memo app from your app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `UIDocumentInteractionController`.
This way you can provide an "Open In" option on .wav file.

My guess is the Voice Memo app has supported file type of .wav extension and you must be able to see that app in Open in option.

Refer [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1) to know how to set up `UIDocumentInteractionController`.